# SQL - assign a value to a group having a specific text

Tags: group-by

Trying to learn SQL.

I have Table 1 below. I want to have Table 2 where if a group has at least a Yes in one of its rows, the group is assigned a Yes on all its rows in the final_joined column. If a group has a No in all its rows, then it is assigned a No on all its rows in the final_joined column.

Apologies if the tables look messy.

My first time to post here.

Thank you.

| group | joined |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes |
| 1 | No |
| 1 | Yes |
| 2 | No |
| 2 | No |
| 3 | Yes |
| 3 | No |

| group | final_joined |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes |
| 1 | Yes |
| 1 | Yes |
| 2 | No |
| 2 | No |
| 3 | Yes |
| 3 | Yes |

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:
Using a subquery and checking if the SUM of 'Yes' is greater than 0 should do the job for you:

```
SELECT 
  t.`group`,
(CASE WHEN  
  (SELECT  SUM(t1.joined='Yes') FROM `test_data` t1 WHERE t1.group=t.`group` ) >0 
  THEN 
  'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS finalJoined
FROM
  test_data t
```

Comment: Hey @Asgar. Thanks but I am getting an error "incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: What vendor are you using? What is the version? I have tested with your data, works fine

Comment: @yoyong555 maybe you should  mention SQL type, because Asgar QUery is for Mysql

Comment: @Asgar Microsoft SQL

Comment: @kucluk how do i do this in with Microsoft SQL?